# .mp4 playback lag on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a video that is controlled by the user scroll, this works really nicely on safari, but on chrome it lags and jumps point to point rather than play smoothly. Is this an issue with my video file or is it something to do with my chrome?

Link to example: https://advancedriderwear.com/Updates/Feature-Test/Video/

Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="set-height"></div>
<div id="time"></div>
<div id="scroll"></div>
<div class="video-stick">
    <video id="v0" tabindex="0" autobuffer="autobuffer" preload="preload">
    <source type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" src="Beast_exploding_animation.mp4"></source>
    <source type="video/ogg; codecs=&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;" src="Beast_exploding_animation.mp4"></source>
    <source type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="Beast_exploding_animation.mp4"></source>
    <p>Sorry, your browser does not support the &lt;video&gt; element.</p>
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background: black;
}

.space{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}

#video-stick{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center'
}

#set-height {
    display: block;
    height: 9000px;
}
  #v0 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    height: 80%;

    margin: auto;
  }

  #time {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  }
  #scroll {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  }
```

JS:

```
// select video element
    var vid = document.getElementById('v0');
    var time = $('#time');
    var scroll = $('#scroll');
    var windowheight = $(window).height()-20;


    var scrollpos = window.pageYOffset/400;
    var targetscrollpos = scrollpos;
    var accel = 0;


    // ---- Values you can tweak: ----
    var accelamount = 0.1; //How fast the video will try to catch up with the target position. 1 = instantaneous, 0 = do nothing.

    // pause video on load
    vid.pause();

    window.onscroll = function(){
        //Set the video position that we want to end up at:
        targetscrollpos = window.pageYOffset/400;

        //move the red dot to a position across the side of the screen
        //that indicates how far we've scrolled.
        scroll.css('top', 10+(window.pageYOffset/5000*windowheight));
    };


    setInterval(function(){  

        //Accelerate towards the target:
        scrollpos += (targetscrollpos - scrollpos)*accelamount;

        //move the blue dot to a position across the side of the screen
        //that indicates where the current video scroll pos is.  
        time.css('top', 10+(scrollpos/5000*400*windowheight));

        //update video playback
        vid.currentTime = scrollpos;
        vid.pause();

    }, 40);
```

Comment: When scrolling to the bottom, both element `#time` and `#scroll` end up with CSS values `top: 18260px`, while my browsers' viewport max-height is 1125px (1920x1200, 24" display), so that can't be right. Tested on Firefox DE, W10. (lags in FF too!)